# How can I test for Connect Four victory condition?

Tags: c, logic

trying to create a connect 4 game. Everything works fine except the victory conditions. Here is the code, appreciate every help. (sorry identifiers are german but i hope you get along with the code). array "spielfeld" is a two-dimensional-array which is initializised with 0. 120 and 111 stand for x and o.

EDIT: only the crucial parts left, sorry for code overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "eingabe.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
```

//initializations

```
int main(void)
{
int spieler = 1;
int won = 0;
while(won == 0)
{
    switch(spieler)
    {
        case 1:
              anzeige(zeilen, spalten, spielfeld);
              auswahl = erfasse_ganze_zahl(0, spalten);
              erfolg = setze(zeilen, spalten, spielfeld, auswahl, 1, 120);
              won = victory_condition(zeilen, spalten, spielfeld);
              break;
        case 2:
              anzeige(zeilen, spalten, spielfeld);
              auswahl = erfasse_ganze_zahl(0, spalten);
              erfolg = setze(zeilen, spalten, spielfeld, auswahl, 1, 111);
              won = victory_condition(zeilen, spalten, spielfeld);
              break;
    }
    return 0;
}   


int setze(int zeilen, int spalten, int spielfeld[zeilen][spalten], int auswahl, int spieler, char wert)
{
    auswahl--;
    for (int i = spalten - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(spielfeld[i][auswahl] == 0)
        {
            spielfeld[i][auswahl] = wert;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}   

void anzeige(int zeilen, int spalten, int spielfeld[zeilen][spalten])
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < spalten; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < zeilen; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", spielfeld[i][j]);
            printf(" | ");
            if (j == zeilen - 1)
            {
                printf("\n");
                for (k = 0; k < spalten; k++)
                    printf("----");
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//some code

```
int victory_condition(int zeilen, int spalten, int spielfeld[zeilen][spalten])
{
    int vertikal = 1;//(|)
    int horizontal = 1;//(-)
    int diagonal1 = 1;//(\)
    int diagonal2 = 1;//(/)
    char spieler = spielfeld[zeilen][spalten];
    int i;
    int j;//horizontal
     //check for vertikal(|)
    for(i = 0; spielfeld[i][spalten] == spieler && i <= zeilen; i++)
        vertikal++;//Check down
    printf("\n%d, %d\n\n%d, %d\n", vertikal, horizontal, diagonal1, diagonal2);
    for(i = zeilen; spielfeld[i][spalten] == spieler && i >= 0; i--)
        vertikal++;//Check up
    printf("\n%d, %d\n\n%d, %d\n", vertikal, horizontal, diagonal1, diagonal2);
    if(vertikal >= 4) return 1;
    //check for horizontal(-)
    for(j = spalten -1; spielfeld[zeilen][j] == spieler && j >= 0; j--,horizontal++);//Check left
        for(j = spalten +1; spielfeld[zeilen][j] == spieler && j <= 6; j++,horizontal++);//Check right
            if(horizontal >= 4) return 1;
    //check for diagonal 1 (\)
    for(i = zeilen -1, j = spalten - 1; spielfeld[i][j] == spieler && i >= 0 && j >= 0; diagonal1 ++, i --, j --);//up and left
        for(i = zeilen +1, j = spalten + 1; spielfeld[i][j] == spieler && i <= 5 && j <= 6; diagonal1 ++, i ++, j ++);//down and right
            if(diagonal1 >= 4) return 1;
    //check for diagonal 2(/)
    for(i = zeilen -1, j= spalten +1;spielfeld[i][j] == spieler && i>=0 && j <= 6; diagonal2 ++, i --, j ++);//up and right
        for(i = zeilen +1, j= spalten -1;spielfeld[i][j] == spieler && i<=5 && j >=0; diagonal2 ++, i ++, j --);//up and left
            if(diagonal2 >= 4) return 1;
    printf("\n%d, %d\n\n%d, %d\n", vertikal, horizontal, diagonal1, diagonal2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Way too much code, and the fact that it is not in English makes it even harder to read through for most of us.  Try to narrow it down to something more reasonable.

Comment: Hooray for Google Translate (somewhat): http://pastebin.com/brsDBHsd

Comment: Just one hint: since the playfield is only 7*6 in size (IIRC) try using a (well: possibly two: for both players) bitmap (or at least a 1 dimentional array) The conditions can be expressed in combinations of cells with the same color on the same line (with no intervening stones of the other color) BTW I can read German. And in this case, it are only the identifiers, that need to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Once a new coin (or pin or whatever) is dropped, just check it's surroundings. I'm doing only the horizontal check here, but the others work in a similar fashion.

```
int x; // position of the dropped token
int y; // position of the dropped token

for(int count = 0, ix = max(0, x - 3); ix < min(width, x + 3); ++ix) { // go through all fields that might be part of the winning row
    if (field[y][x] == mycolor) { // if it's the active player's color...
        if (++count == 4) // increase the count and check whether there are enough tokens
            winner = true;
    }
    else // if the color doesn't match...
        count = 0; // reset the count
}
```